# PHP/MySQL insert form

Tags: php, mysql

As soon as you enter the web page it enters into the SQL table, even if you do not submit, immediately after you enter the web page it sends a blank to the SQL table, here is the codes both the HTML form and the PHP form.

```
<form name="" method="POST" action="">
<input class="" type="text" name="a1" id="a1" class="placeholder" placeholder="Enter the FRATERNITY Name">
<input class="" type="text" name="a2" id="a2" class="placeholder" placeholder="Enter YOUR Name">
<style>

<?php

$host="";
$username="";
$password="";
$database_name="";
$table_name="";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$database_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$a1=$_POST['a1'];
$a2=$_POST['a2'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $table_name(groupname, founder)VALUES('$a1', '$a2')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Group $a1 Has Been Created";

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check it if it's a post request, and then only execute your code. See below:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $host="";
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $database_name="";
    $table_name="";

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$database_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $a1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a1']);
    $a2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a2']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO $table_name(groupname, founder)VALUES('$a1', '$a2')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
    echo "Group $a1 Has Been Created";

    }

    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }
    ?> 

    <?php 
    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
}
```

Note that your code as it stands is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. I've untainted the two input strings to protect against this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes a lot of sense, I really do appreciate your answer!

Comment: Welcome, and note: `mysql_*` functions are depreciated and will be removed in future, so use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: i understand exactly what you pointed out to me and added, yet it is still only refreshing when submitted nothing happens. ALTHOUGH, it is not sending blanks into the database any longer.

Comment: after if you refresh, browser will prompt you that you are again sending the post request, to prevent this, you can redirect to the same page, at the end like `header('location:thesamepage.php');`

Comment: <input id="" type="submit" value="Create" name="submit">
could the submit button have anything to do with it?

Comment: i noticed how i didnt show the button in the script above

Comment: First time, you can press submit button, on press enter on text box  - it will submit your form, 

and if your form already posted (but not redirected), and you do refresh, it will execute your code again, with the data you've filled previously - hope you understand

Comment: ftr, depreciation is what happens to assets, they lose value.  Deprecation is when software is no longer supported.

Comment: @Kamal: it's worth getting into the habit of alerting posters to SQL injection vulnerabilities in their code. You've replicated the problem here in your own answer - would you edit it to show how `mysql_real_escape_string()` can be used to prevent attacks?

Comment: @halfer Mine was just example, how to get it done, however Agree to you, that it should be in practice :), updated answer respectively!